# How to check whether an attribute of an object has a value?

Tags: perl, bioperl

I get an error such as "can't call method 'xxxx' on an undefined value" when attempting to check if an object has been created (by the perl module Bio::Perl).

Is there a general way of checking if an attribute has a value or not? I would have liked to do something like:

```
if ($the_object->the_attribute) {
```

But as long as the attribute is "undef", calling the method will only give me the error message. I have not been able to find a solution to this problem - which is real, because the object is created by the Bio::Perl module, and some attributes may or may not be set. Maybe I should add that I am not particularly perl-objects-savvy.

edit:
Below is a relevant part of my code. The get_sequence() function is in the Bio::Perl module. On line 13, how can I make sure that there is a value (sequence in this case) before checking the length of it?

```
my @msgs;
my @sequence_objects;
my $maxlength = 0;

for ( @contigs ) {

    my $seq_obj;

    try {
        $seq_obj = get_sequence( 'genbank', $_ );
    }
    catch Bio::Root::Exception with {
        push @msgs, "Nothing found for $_ ";
    };

    if ( $seq_obj ) {

        my $seq_length = length( $seq_obj->seq );

        if ( $seq_length > $maxlength ) {
            $maxlength = $seq_length;
        }

        push @sequence_objects, $seq_obj;
    }
}

...
```

Comment: No. You're not checking if the obj has been created. You are checking the return value of `$the_object->the_attribute` and the error message means that `$the_object` is not an object, but `undef`. If you include a bit more code (like where `$the_object` came from, and what attributes it is supposed to have), I can refine my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> if ($the_object->the_attribute) {
> ```

This checks if the return value of the method `the_attribute` is true. *True* means that it's not `0`, the empty string `q{}` or `undef`.

But you said you want to know whether the object exists.

Let's go over **some basics** first.

```
#   | this variable contains an object
#   |          this arrow -> tells Perl to call the method on the obj    
#   |          | this is a method that is called on $the_object
#   |          | |        
if ($the_object->the_attribute) {
#  (                          )
# the if checks the return value of the expression between those parenthesis
```

It looks like you're confusing a few things.

First, your `$the_object` is supposed to be an object. It probably came from a call like this:

```
my $the_object = Some::Class->new;
```

Or maybe it was returned from some other function call. Maybe some other object returned it.

```
my $the_object = $something_else->some_property_that_be_another_obj
```

Now `the_attribute` is a method (that's like a function) that returns a specific piece of data in your object. Depending on the implementation of the class (the building plan of the object), if that attribute is not set (*initialized*), it might either just return `undef`, or some other value.

But the error message you are seeing is not related to `the_attribute`. If it was, you'd just not call the code in the block. The `if` check would catch it, and decide to go to `else`, or do nothing if there is no `else`.

Your error message says you are trying to call a method on something that is `undef`. We know you are calling the `the_attribute` accessor method on `$the_object`. So `$the_object` is `undef`.

---

The easiest way to check if something has a true value is to just put it in an `if`. But you already seem to know that.

```
if ($obj) {
    # there is some non-false value in $obj
}
```

You've now checked that `$obj` is something that is true. So it could be an object. So you could now call your method.

```
if ($obj && $obj->the_attribute) { ... }
```

This will check the true-ness of `$obj` and only continue if there is something in `$obj`. If not, it will never call the right hand side of the `&&` and you will not get an error.

But if you want to know whether `$obj` is an object that has a method, you can use `can`. Remember that *attributes* are just accessor methods to values stored inside the object.

```
if ($obj->can('the_attribute')) {
    # $obj has a method the_attribute
}
```

But that can blow up if `$obj` is not there.

If you're not sure that `$obj` is really an object, you can use the [Safe::Isa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe::Isa) module. It provides a method `$_call_if_object`<sup>1</sup> that you can use to safely call your method on your maybe-object.

```
$maybe_an_object->$_call_if_object(method_name => @args);
```

Your call would translate to.

```
my $the_attribute = $obj->$_call_if_object('the_attribute');
if ($the_attribute) {
    # there is a value in the_attribute
}
```

The same way you can use `$_isa` and `$_can` from Safe::Isa.

---

<sup>1) Yes, the method starts with a `$`, it's really a variable. If you want to learn more about how and why this works, watch the talk [*You did what?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aCsUxfRksE) by mst.</sup>

Comment: I see now that I had misunderstood/mixed up the original error message as it should have been related to an (non existing) object, and not be related to the method. Many thanks for your thorough explanation!